# Searching Data from DataGrid Control using ADODC in VB6.0

Tags: visual-studio, datagrid, vb6

I'm a student doing my final year mini project and am facing a problem related to searching data in the datagrid.
The error I'm getting is :

> Run-time error : '3001'
>   Arguments are of wront type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another

The code is :

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim item As String
    Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst
    item = Text1.Text
    Adodc1.Recordset.Find "L_No = " & item
    If Adodc1.Recordset.EOF Then
        MsgBox "Record Set not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code is working when the data I'm searching is only number.
For example 
When I search the data on the basis of L_Id which is a License ID an Integer value the searching is done and I'm getting the result.
When I search the data on the basis of L_No which is a License Number a string value which consists of both numbers and alphabets I'm getting the above error.

Do I have to parse the value is text1.text or do anything else?

Answer (score 1):

When the field you're searching in is not a numeric type, you'll want to delimit it with single quotes:

```
Adodc1.Recordset.Find "L_No = '" & item & "'"
```